# Xamarin Android throws IOException when using ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory method

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I try to use the following code in my project without any success and it's driving me mad.

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filePath, appPath);
```

The parameters are:

```
filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Flashback_Backup/memory_backup.zip"
appPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Flashback"
```

According to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx) IOException should be thrown if:

> The directory specified by destinationDirectoryName already exists.
>   -or- The name of an entry in the archive is Empty, contains only white space, or contains at least one invalid character.
>   -or- Extracting an archive entry would create a file that is outside the directory specified by destinationDirectoryName. (For example,
>   this might happen if the entry name contains parent directory
>   accessors.)
>   -or- An archive entry to extract has the same name as an entry that has already been extracted from the same archive.

As far as I know none of it applies. The zip file is a totally valid one, which I compressed with the Directory.CreateDirectory method, and only contains a few uniquely named JSON files. I tried with and without existing "Flashback" folder too, but nothing seems to work.

If anyone have any ideas or solutions please tell me because I'm seriously lost at this. I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: did you check your privileges?

Comment: I have added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE alongside a few irrelevant ones. I think it should be enough, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap extraction intro try-catch, it may give you a better understanding of what is going on.

```
try {
    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filePath, appPath);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.Log(ex);
}
```

If there is an error, it will be one of your listed above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's an invalid parameter error. Still no idea what can cause the problem. I tried without the '_' in the paths, but nothing changes.